# A single Sequelize query for querying an association that has an association

Tags: sequelize.js

I have 3 models : Report, Branch, Client.

```
Report.belongsTo(Branch);
Branch.belongsTo(Client);
```

When querying a report with its related branch and client I run 2 queries:

```
Report.findOne({
        where:{id:reportId},
        include: [{
            model: Branch,
            attributes: ['name','clientId']
        }]
    })
        .then((report)=>{
            const clientId = report.dataValues.branch.clientId;
            Client.findOne({
                where:{id:clientId},
            })
                .then((client)=>{
                    console.log('client is ', client);
                });
        })
        .catch();
```

Can I query the data with only one query that connects Report->Branch->Client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, includes can be nested within each other. Assuming the association `Branch.belongsTo(Client);` is set up correctly you should be able to do:

```
Report.findOne({
    where: {
        id: reportId
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: Branch,
            attributes: [ 'name', 'clientId' ],
            include: [
                {
                    model: Client
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```